# Spring boot doesnt recognize Pattern when set through another annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation

I have to validate a Rest API dto for email and number. For this I am using a custom pattern to validate the value inside the dto. Using the @Pattern() with the regex works properly. However, using another annotation annotated with @Pattern doesn't validate my DTO.

```java
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{7,14}", message = "Message should be digit")
public @interface IsNumber {
}


public class MyDTO {
@IsNumber
private String number;
}

@PostMapping(...)
public GenericResponse addNumber(@Valid @RequestBody MyDTO myDto) {}
```

The API endpoint allows the DTO to pass through and access my service, when infact the validation should have blocked the request

Comment: Did you forget `@Constraint` on `IsNumber`? (This isn't a *Spring* thing, it's a Bean Validation thing.)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the @Constraint(validatedBy={}) solved the problem. This annotation will invokes the validation code that checks the regex pattern.

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{7,14}", message = "Message should be digit")
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface IsNumber {
}
```